# What does number at the bottom of Netbeans serves for

Tags: netbeans, ide

I've been wondering for a few year... What is that number at the bottom of Netbeans  IDE?

What does represents?[image: Netbeans IDE example]

Comment: Line number and column number?

Comment: That number at the bottom, the end of the IDE, the one with the red circle

Comment: You misunderstand me -- I know which number you mean, I was saying that I think that the number indicates the cursor's current line number and column number.

Comment: Now that U're saying I see that the first changes according the line I click, but I'm not sure if the other is the column

Comment: [NetBeans manual - How to use the status line](http://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG159)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are representing where your cursor is right now, the row number and the character from left.